# Checking if a record exists in Sinatra/DataMapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I currently generate a user's profile page using their serial ID, like so:

```
get '/users/:id' do
  @user = User.get(params[:id])
end
```

This works great, until a number is entered that doesn't exist in the database.

I'm aware I can change `User.get` to `User.get!` to return an `ObjectNotFoundError` error if the record isn't found, but I'm not sure how I can use this to my aid.

I used to use `.exists?` when using RoR.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: I'm going to leave the question unanswered, as I haven't actually found a solution to what I asked in the title; however, I did manage to solve my own problem by checking to see if the :id entered is higher than the amount of users that exist in the database, like so:**

```
if params[:id].to_i > User.count
  "This user does not exist."
else
  @users_id = User.get(params[:id])
  erb(:'users/id')
end
```

Comment: just curious, since you can throw an `ObjectNotFoundError ` why not catch it and redirect to 404 not found page? P.S never tried sinatra, just rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the correct code:

```
@user = User.get(params[:id])
```

If no user exists with the given id, then `#get` will return nil. Then you can just do a conditional:

```
@user = User.get params[:id]
if @user
  # user exists
else
  # no user exists
end
```

This is a very common pattern in Ruby which takes advantage of the "truthiness" of anything other than `false` or `nil`. i.e. you can say `if 0` or `if []` and the condition will evaluate to true

You can recreate a [`.exists?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class) method:

```
class User
  def self.exists?(id_or_conditions)
    if id_or_conditions.is_a? Integer
      !! User.get id_or_conditions
    else
      !! User.first id_or_conditions
    end
  end
end
```

`#get` is similar to `#find` in rails, except it doesn't raise an error if the record is not found. `#first` is similar to `#find_by` in rails.

Comment: Hey Max. This is perfect - thank you! I really appreciate all your help.